# Print a string and display the newlines & tabs in their character format

Tags: c#, string

I am parsing a html file for one simple line. So I am not using a 3rd party library just normal string functions(`s.subString()` etc.).

**My problem** is I cannot correctly find specific elements in the HTML because they contain tab characters, endlines, carriage returns.

**How can I print the following string to display all the carriage returns as \r, all endlines as \n & etc.** So I can then see exactly the layout of the HTML file & ensure my

```
.subString("<div class=\"x\">")
```

is not failing because the text is really

```
("<div \t\r\nclass=\"x\">"
```

or something?

My code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string html = wc.DownloadString(String.Format("http://www.ipchecking.com/?ip={0}&check=Lookup", ip));

Console.Write( html ); // I want to print in the raw form where \r characters are actually shown as \r characters
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser. The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is popular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
html = html.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n","\\n").Replace("\t","\\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be using regular expressions REGEX:

[Sample Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

Comment: first of all thank you, second i can read certian html tags after saving them in a string, why not?